# Why is a LTS release not using the Extended Support Version of Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, 12.04, lts

Precise Pangolin (12.04) is a **LTS** (Long Term Support) release of Ubuntu. Why is Thunderbird **11** included, instead of Thunderbird **10 ESR** (Extended Support Release)?

Is there any way to install Thunderbird 10 ESR on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I think Jo-Erlend's answer is sufficient, but if you'd like to install Thunderbird ESR, you can donwload it here: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/all-esr.html You simply need to extract it into your home folder and add a script called `~/bin/thunderbird` to launch `~/thunderbird_folder/thunderbird $@` every time your user calls `thunderbird`

Comment: @Githlar - remember this is a collaborative website - so feel free to edit Jo-Erlend's answer with just this information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because we use Firefox 11 instead of ESR and most of the same reasons apply to Thunderbird as Firefox for using the rapid release version. The decision to not use ESR by default in the LTS was surprising to me, so I asked on the mailinglists (you can find the thread here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2012-February/003672.html) and Jason Warner from Canonical answered:

> Firefox adopted a rapid release model for various reasons, but among them
>   was that they needed the browser to keep up with the pace of innovation on
>   the internet. Ubuntu needs to be out in front of these things and be
>   pushing the very edge of what is possible, particularly in the browser. I
>   do not think we can ship a browser that will lag by 12 months in any sense;
>   the risks too far outweigh the rewards.
>
> I'm afraid that even a year lag (ESR update period) would put Ubuntu at
>   severe disadvantage to other platforms. Imagine a world where G+ or
>   Facebook or some new whizbang product didn't work on Ubuntu because the
>   browser shipped didn't support some new technology/javascript
>   engine/platform component. That is neither something we want nor can
>   afford. We have to be better, we have to be faster and we have to be
>   braver.

Anyway, you'd like to install Thunderbird ESR, you can donwload it here: http://mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/organizations/all-esr.html 
You simply need to extract it into your home folder and add a script called `~/bin/thunderbird` 
to launch 
`~/thunderbird_folder/thunderbird $@` 
every time your user calls thunderbird

You can also see [this blog post](http://www.chriscoulson.me.uk/blog/?p=111) from Chris Coulson on why the ESR was not selected.

Comment: Yet? Hopefully never. But Jason's right. While LTS is a conservative release, there are still areas that need to be bleeding-edge for security purposes. Plus, I don't think there'd be any problem as Mozilla puts out very solid releases. I've been using Firefox since 1.5 and I can only remember one botch release (Kind of like that one botched Ubuntu release. 8.04 I think?)

Comment: Some companies can't have dedicated staff working continuously on porting addons and webapps though. It wouldn't even be an option to maintain a fork for the sake of being stable, but asking for an ESR in an LTS isn't unreasonable. But we will have it available. We'll just use a lesser stable, but more advanced browser by default. It's not a bad decision, as long as Mozilla keeps doing things in small increments.

Comment: I haven't find this dicussion thanks Jo-Erlend. But i think that Firefox is a difference product respect Thunderbird. My customers are using TB 3.1 from a lot of time without problem. **It's not necessary to update a client mail so frequently**, if you have already security patches.

Comment: @Alessio: True, it's not necessary to update an email client as frequently. However, once you have made the transition to the newest Thunderbird, you will find that the incremental changes every six weeks or so are straight-foward, easy, quick, and non-intrusive. I agree with Canonical's decision.

Comment: @PaddyLandau the only problem for me is to keep update my addons! We use sogo addons (www.sogo.nu) and we should upate those every two months :-( With ESR we can update once a year